# XPath validation using Regex

Tags: c#, xml, regex, validation, xpath

Try as much as possible to describe the problem in detail. 
For example, I have xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
   <paths>
      <path>
         <file>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>example</name>
     </file>
     <options>
        <isreadonly>true</isreadonly>
     </options>
      </path>
   </paths>
</root>
```

And have XPahts:

- root/paths/path/file/id
- root/paths/path/file/name
- root/paths/path/options/isreadonly

How to validate this paths with regex?

I can validate one xml element name with this regex - ^(?!XML)[a-zA-Z][\w]*$, but I need String.Split(this string) and then use regex in loop.

This is naming rules of xml element name:

- Names can contain letters, numbers, and other characters
- Names cannot start with a number or punctuation character
- Names cannot start with the letters xml (or XML, or Xml, etc)
- Names cannot contain spaces

Not valid paths:

- xml/...
- .../xmlang/...
- .../1asdf/...
- 1/.../...
- .../_asdf/... etc.

Thanks.

Comment: `XPathExpression.Compile` ?

Comment: I need a simply regex string. I need to mark a property of model with [RegularExpression("")] attribute or use this regular expression on the client side with java script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to mark a property on your model anyway you would just make a custom property that checks if the expression compiles.
This will be a lot easyer then trying to regex it.
As since regex is not the tool you want to parse => https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113237/when-you-should-not-use-regular-expressions (see the accepted answer).

A custom attribute can be made as following:

```
public class MyCustomAttribute : ValidationAttribute {
protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
     {
        //Your logic here.
        return ValidationResult.Success;
     }
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering does the language defines XPath's syntax is regular or not? have you any information about that?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: Are you familiar with language theories, right? actually, XPath syntax defines a language that determines whether a given string is in the language or not, in other words it determines whether it can be considered as valid Xpath. only if the language is regular we can write a regular expression that generates the same language else we can not. for example if the language is Context-free language we only describe it using a parser and there is no way to define it using a regular expression. So my question is Do you know what the class of Xpath syntax language belongs to.

Comment: I have the same question about JsonPath syntax because these two syntaxes have lots of common

Comment: In my opinion both aren't regular and should only be parsed by a parser. None the less it's not impossible to use regular expressions on them like it's not impossible to do the same for HTML. It's just something most would frown upon.